# Is the main point of dependency injection being pass dependencies to target's function(or constructor) rather than create them inside the target?

Tags: c++, angularjs, design-patterns

Just finished a AngularJS course, the term dependency injection is used all over the place. Am I right the main point of it is: **pass dependent objects to target's function(or constructor) rather than create them inside the target**?

I get the benefit of it, easy for unit testing, etc. But I've been doing it in other areas, mainly c++ with googlemock, without knowing there is a term Dependency Injection for it. So am I missing something? I guess Angular's DI has to manage lifetime of those services, factories as well as passing them into the requesting object, but that should be the implementation detail and not part of Dependency Inject concept?

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108222/solid-principle-examples-anywhere/13109003#13109003). It's not Angular-specific but should go some way to answer your question(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing particularly magic about "dependency injection", but it's a useful model for keeping responsibilities isolated and dependencies flexible. Improved testability is one pleasant side effect, but at its heart dependency injection is just a particular manifestation of the principles of locality and single responsibility.

Here's a typical C++ example. First, consider how a class `Foo` may have grown organically:

```
class Foo
{
 public:
    Foo(A a, B b, C c)
    : a_(a), widget_(b, c) {}

 private:
    A a_;
    Widget widget_;
 };
```

The functionality of `Foo` presumably requires some internal object of `Widget` type. But note how the construction (and potential failure!) of the `widget_` object is the responsibility of `Foo`'s constructor. Not only do we need to pass all the required arguments through `Foo`, but inversely, `Foo` also needs to handle all the potential failure modes of the `Widget` constructor. And on top of that we're locked into using a single version of `Widget` (and we need to include transitively all of `Widget`'s definitions in the `Foo` translation unit).

Enter dependency injection:

```
struct AbstractWidget { ~AbstractWidget() = default; };

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(A a, std::unique_ptr<AbstractWidget> widget)
    : a_(a), widget_(std::move(widget)) {}

private:
    A a_;
    std::unique_ptr<AbstractWidget> widget_;
};
```

Now the dependency of `Foo` on abstact "widget" functionality is *injected* into `Foo` objects by the constructor. The widget object is already fully constructed and operational in ways that don't concern us any longer. `Foo` now only does one thing. A popular mnemonic is to "depend on abstractions, not concretions".

That's really all there is to it at a first glance.

Dependency injection in some languages (such as Java, and presumably JavaScript) is known and taught more prominently there because there exists powerful *frameworks* to automate the construction of designs that use DI. Such automations may include automatic definitions of the relevant constructors, and they may go as far as making the "injection" point far removed from the constructed instance, which makes the ultimate effective dependency in the running program far more dynamic than what one would expect in a typical C++ program.

Comment: It's worth noting that this approach has many limitations in C++ that don't apply elsewhere, such as no use of templated functions.

Comment: @Puppy: I'd probably prefer saying that C++ offers many alternative design options (e.g. templated functor arguments) that often make for a better solution for many problems for which other languages might advocate DI as the primary approach. The DI approach I showed has its uses, but you shouldn't try to fit every problem to it.