# Difference between dependency injection and dependency inversion

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection, dependency-inversion

Two design patterns namely Dependency Injection and Dependency Inversion exist out there, Articles are there in the net trying to explain the difference. But the need to explain it in easier words is still there. Any one  out there to come up to ?

I need to understand it in PHP.

Comment: Not PHP, but check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13109003/1162077

Comment: If you're going to ask a duplicate question, at the very least you should link the articles and posts that you've read and list the details that you didn't understand.

Comment: @jaco0646, I said about articles that are not in SO.

Answer (score 231):

*(Note: This answer is language-agnostic, although the question specifically mentions PHP, but being unfamiliar with PHP, I have not provided any PHP examples)*.

#### Terminology - Dependencies and Coupling

In the context of Object-Oriented Programming, a *dependency* is any other *object type* which a class has a **direct** relationship with.  When a class *depends* directly upon another object type, it can be described as being **coupled** to that type.

In general, *any* type used by a class is a dependency to some extent.   There are many different ways for a class to depend upon another type, including:

- Object types used by Instance variables
- Object types used by Constructor parameters
- Object types used by Accessor/Mutator methods
- Constructors (And sometimes methods) which create new objects directly
- Inheritance

The stronger the relationship between a class and its dependency, the tighter the coupling;  therefore when a class depends directly upon another concrete class (such as the case with inheritance creating a direct dependency on a base class, or the case where a constructor creates new objects for its instance variables), any future changes to that direct dependency are more likely to "ripple" across in a Butterfly-effect style.

---

#### Difference Between Injection vs Inversion

- Dependency **Injection** is an *[Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)* technique for supplying *objects* ('dependencies') to a class by way of the [Dependency Injection Design Pattern](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).   Typically passing dependencies via one of the following:

  - A constructor
  - A public property or field
  - A public setter
- The Dependency **Inversion** Principle (DIP) is a software design *guideline* which boils down to two recommendations about [de-coupling a class from its concrete dependencies](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/22/dependency-injection-is-not-the-same-as-the-dependency-inversion-principle/):

  1. *'High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.'*
  2. *'Abstractions should not depend upon details. Details should depend upon abstractions.'*

Or, to put it even more succinctly:

- Dependency Injection is an implementation technique for populating instance variables of a class.
- Dependency Inversion is a general design guideline which recommends that classes should only have direct relationships with high-level abstractions.

---

#### Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control (IoC)

Dependency Injection applies the IoC principle by ensuring classes are never responsible for creating or supplying their own dependencies (and therefore aren't responsible for the lifetime of those dependencies either).

However, ***IoC is not Dependency Injection*** - indeed, IoC as a principle has nothing particularly to do with dependencies or dependency injection per-se;  Dependency Injection is a design pattern based around the principle of IoC.

IoC is seen in many other contexts, including those totally unrelated to object creation or dependencies, such as message passing via a Mediator or Message pump to trigger event handlers.  Other (unrelated) examples of IoC include:

- A windowed application using event handler functions/methods to handle mouse/keyboard input events.
- An MVC web application using Controller Actions to handle HTTP requests.

*(Updated from the original answer as a separate explanation about IoC)*

---

#### Dependency Injection Pattern

Dependency Injection is a design pattern which applies the IoC principle to ensure that a class has absolutely no involvement or awareness in the creation or lifetime of objects used by its constructor or instance variables -- the "common" concern about object creation and populating instance variables is deferred to a framework instead.

That is to say, a class may specify its instance variables, but does not do any work to populate those instance variables (with the exception of using constructor parameters as a "pass-through")

A class which is designed with *Dependency Injection* in mind may look like this:

```
// Dependency Injection Example...

class Foo {
    // Constructor uses DI to obtain the Meow and Woof dependencies
    constructor(fred: Meow, barney: Woof) {
        this.fred = fred;
        this.barney = barney;
    }
}
```

In this example, `Meow` and `Woof` are both dependencies *injected* via the `Foo` constructor.

On the other hand, a `Foo` class which is designed *without* Dependency Injection might simply create the `Meow` and `Woof` instances itself, or perhaps use some kind of service locator/factory:

```
// Example without Dependency Injection...

class Foo {
    constructor() {
        // a 'Meow' instance is created within the Foo constructor
        this.fred = new Meow();

        // a service locator gets a 'WoofFactory' which in-turn
        // is responsible for creating a 'Woof' instance.
        // This demonstrates IoC but not Dependency Injection.
        var factory = TheServiceLocator.GetWoofFactory();
        this.barney = factory.CreateWoof();
    }
}
```

So dependency injection simply means that a class has deferred *responsibility* of obtaining or providing its own dependencies; instead that responsibility resides with whatever wants to create an instance.   (Which is usually an IoC Container)

---

#### Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP)

Dependency Inversion is broadly about de-coupling concrete classes by preventing those classes having any **direct** reference to each other.

The DIP is primarily concerned with ensuring that a class only depends upon higher-level abstractions.    For example, interfaces exist at a higher level of abstraction than a concrete class.

The DIP is not about injecting dependencies, although the dependency injection pattern is one of many techniques which can help provide the level of indirection needed to avoid depending on low-level details and coupling with other concrete classes.

*Note: Dependency Inversion is often more explicit in statically typed programming languages such as C# or Java, because those languages enforce strict type-checking on variable names.   On the other hand, Dependency Inversion is already passively available in dynamic languages such as Python or JavaScript because variables in those languages do not have any particular type restrictions.*

Consider a scenario in a statically typed language where a class requires the ability to read a record from the application's database:

```
// class Foo depends upon a concrete class called SqlRecordReader.

class Foo {
    reader: SqlRecordReader;

    constructor(sqlReader: SqlRecordReader) {
        this.reader = sqlReader;
    }

    doSomething() {
        var records = this.reader.readAll();
        // etc.
    }
}
```

In the above example, and despite the use of Dependency Injection, class `Foo` still has a hard dependency on `SqlRecordReader`, yet the only thing it really cares about is that there exists a method called `readAll()` which returns some records.

Consider the situation where SQL database queries are later refactored out into separate micro-services requiring a change to the codebase; the `Foo` class would need to read records from a remote service instead.    Or alternatively, a situation where `Foo` unit tests need to read data from an in-memory store or a flat file.

If, as its name suggests, the `SqlRecordReader` contains database and SQL logic, any move to microservices would need the `Foo` class to change.

Dependency Inversion guidelines suggest that `SqlRecordReader` should be replaced with a higher-level abstraction which only provides the `readAll()` method.  i.e:

```
interface IRecordReader {
    Records[] getAll();
}

class Foo {
    reader: IRecordReader;

    constructor(reader: IRecordReader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }
}
```

As per DIP, the `IRecordReader` is a *higher-level* abstraction than `SqlRecordReader`.  Changing `Foo` to depend on `IRecordReader` instead of `SqlRecordReader` satisfies DIP guidelines.

---

#### Why DIP Guidelines are Useful

The keyword is *guideline* - dependency inversion adds indirection to the design of your program.   The obvious disadvantage of adding any kind of indirection is that the complexity (i.e. the cognitive "load" required for a human to understand what's going on) increases.

In many cases, indirection can make code easier to maintain (fix bugs, add enhancements) however:

In this last example, `Foo` *might* receive a `SqlRecordReader`, or maybe a `SoapRecordReader`, or perhaps a `FileRecordReader`, or maybe even for unit testing a `MockRecordReader` - the point is that it doesn't know or care anything about different possible implementations of `IRecordReader` - provided of course those implementations live up to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Furthermore, it avoids the potentially dirty scenario where a developer who is in a rush to get something working might consider trying to "fudge" the Liskov principle by inheriting the `SoapRecordReader` or `FileRecordReader` from a base class `SqlRecordReader`.

Worse still, an inexperienced developer might even change the `SqlRecordReader` itself so that class has logic not only for SQL but also for SOAP endpoints, The Filesystem, and anything else which might be needed.  (This kind of thing happens too often in the real world - especially in poorly maintained code, and is nearly always a [Code Smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).)

Comment: are dependency inversion and Inversion of Control (IoC) the same ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Related but different: *Dependency Inversion* is about "details depend on abstractions" (i.e. de-coupling so that a class doesn't depend on other concrete classes), whereas *Inversion of Control (IoC)* is about being able to use some kind of generic framework for the creation/wiring of objects and providing dependencies.   IoC can also be about using a generic framework to actually control objects via some kind of generic interface too  (For example, a bunch of different classes which each implement their own `Run()` method which can be invoked by the generic framework)

Comment: This might provide some better context about IoC:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control

Comment: from the Wikipedia link you mentioned: ' In this method, custom-written portions of a computer program receive the flow of control from a generic framework' - can you explain the 3 terms with a example code in IoC perspective :1) custom-written portions 2) flow of control  3) generic framework ?

Comment: I'm wondering, as `IRecordReader` is already an abstraction and hence solves the problem of directly depending on implementation details, why is it still recommended to pass `IRecordReader` from the outside? And wouldn't then the class which uses `Foo` be dependant on `IRecordReader` instead? It feels like the `IRecordReader` dependency is just being moved.

Comment: i think it's better to explain the differences rather than give big whole explanations about each , and then leave it up to the reader to figure out what the difference is.

I still can't tell if there is one or not. Conceptually, they're different. but do they manifest in code as the same syntactically - pass things as an arg/param?

And how does this 3rd player, IoC relate to the other two? is IoC a synonym of one? or is it a third entity? You mention it but don't explain it. Now there are 3 diffs for the reader to make in their heads instead of 1. Example that is IoC but not Dep Inv

Comment: Which of 8 possibilities are unique/possible?
code that does/doesn't have D-inj, D-inv, IoC?

Or is it that if you have one, you have all three?

Comment: @ahnbizcad  Thanks for the comment; to answer briefly, they're somewhat orthogonal, DIP refers to levels of abstraction on class relationships expressed in the code (i.e. the "big picture" design/structure; for example, depending upon an interface instead of a concrete class).  On the other hand, Dependency Injection turns the "wiring" between objects into a run-time decision rather than being a compile-time decision baked into the code for that class - i.e. it becomes a matter of flow-control rather than a matter of code structure.  I've made some changes to try to make this clearer.

Answer (score 31):

See this article [here](https://www.daedtech.com/dependency-injection-or-inversion/)

The author differentiates these two in simple words. **Dependency Injection == “Gimme it” and Dependency Inversion == “Someone take care of this for me, somehow.”**. In dependency inversion principle, high level module is the owner of the abstraction. Thus the detail(implementation of the abstraction) is depends on the abstraction and hence depends on the high level module. Dependency inverted!.. Dependency injection is different. The abstraction might not be kept by the high level module. Thus an abstraction given to the higher level object might not be limited to the needs of the high level module.

Dependency inversion :

You have a higher level module X and an abstraction Y which is defined by X. Z implements Y and is given to X. Thus Z is dependent of X(via the abstraction Y defined by X).

Dependency injection:

You have an higher level module X which needs functionalities A and B. Y is an abstraction which contains the functionalities A, B and C. Z implements Y. Since Z implements Y and hence have functionalities A and B, Z is given to X. Now X is dependent of Y.

Comment: saw this before however. can you summarize that in easier words here ?

Comment: Please see the updated answer if it is you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**Dependancy injection** is ability of object to supply depndcies of other object. in simple words it means something else is dependent on something else. Example Class A uses few functions of Class B now Class A needs to create the instance of Class B here the use of DI comes in to use.

**IOC** is to invert the different resposibilities for example you need to work at home but you need to cook to eat now listed cooking at home you can order it online and it is available to your door step which means you can focus on your work.  Here you inverted cooking responsibilities to online restorent.

The Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP) states that high level modules should not depend on low level modules; both should depend on abstractions. Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend upon abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection is one way to achieve Inversion of Control (which I am assuming you are referring to as Dependency Inversion), so the two aren’t really in competition as much as DI is a specialization of IoC. Other commonly seen ways to achieve IoC include using factories or the Service Locator pattern.

Comment: No Dependency Inversion is not equal to Inversion of Control ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Dependency inversion has nothing to do with both dependency injection or inversion of control. Dependency inversion is the "D" in the SOLID principle. Please refer to the other answers for more in-depth insight, and google search SOLID

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Inversion: How you design your classes and interfaces (high-level should depend on abstractions, not on low-level details).

```
public interface ILog
{
    void WriteLog(string message);
}

public class Log : ILog
{
    public void WriteLog(string message)
    {
        // Implementation details...
    }
}

public class Test
{
    private readonly ILog _obj;

    public Test(ILog obj)
    {
        _obj = obj;
    }

    // Other members...
}
```

Dependency Injection: The mechanism of supplying or "injecting" those dependencies to a class (either manually or using a framework)
In some DI setup code, like Program.cs in ASP.NET Core ex of implementing Dependency Injection:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<ILog, Log>();
```