# Best pattern to change target respository implementation through configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I am not very experienced in design patterns.

I am creating an webapi application using asp.net core 2.0. I want to implement a design pattern so that i can configure whether to use database repository to save to sql database or file repository for saving to file or i will use messaging service to send as a message to a queue.

Can anyone suggest me what is the best pattern to achieve this?

Comment: *"I want to implement a design pattern"* Keep in mind, that design patterns are not blueprints for implementations - they are meant as a way of communicating a basic idea or concept to other developers.

Comment: You can use ServiceLocator Pattren. And base of app configuration return correct Implementation of  data access Interface.

Comment: Do you want to encapsulate object Creation or Behaviour ?
meaning your concern is how to create these 3 types of objects at the runtime or objects will be created already you want to dynamically save to different Target for every request\response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a pattern here. You need to adhere to the SOLID design principles and, in particular, the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://deviq.com/dependency-inversion-principle/).

Create an interface for your repository and depend on that where you want to use it. Inject the appropriate concrete implementation (database or file) as necessary. Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13109003/1162077) for some, highly contrived, ideas.

Comment: Thank you. It really helps.